# Did Moshe give 1/50 of the donkeys, sheep and cattle to the Levi'im?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, animals, levites-leviyim, mattos

Numbers 31:30 says: (Sefaria.org translation), describing G-d's command to Moshe:

> וּמִמַּחֲצִ֨ת בְּנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֜ל תִּקַּ֣ח ׀ אֶחָ֣ד ׀ אָחֻ֣ז מִן־הַחֲמִשִּׁ֗ים מִן־הָאָדָ֧ם מִן־הַבָּקָ֛ר מִן־הַחֲמֹרִ֥ים וּמִן־הַצֹּ֖אן מִכָּל־הַבְּהֵמָ֑ה וְנָתַתָּ֤ה אֹתָם֙ לַלְוִיִּ֔ם שֹׁמְרֵ֕י מִשְׁמֶ֖רֶת מִשְׁכַּ֥ן יְהוָֽה׃
>
> And of the children of Israel’s half, thou shalt take one drawn out of every fifty, of the persons, of the beeves, of the asses, and of the flocks, even of all the cattle, and give them unto the Levites, that keep the charge of the tabernacle of the LORD.’

But, in describing what Moshe actually did, it says:

Numbers 31:47:

> וַיִּקַּ֨ח מֹשֶׁ֜ה מִמַּחֲצִ֣ת בְּנֵֽי־יִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל אֶת־הָֽאָחֻז֙ אֶחָ֣ד מִן־הַחֲמִשִּׁ֔ים מִן־הָאָדָ֖ם וּמִן־הַבְּהֵמָ֑ה וַיִּתֵּ֨ן אֹתָ֜ם לַלְוִיִּ֗ם שֹֽׁמְרֵי֙ מִשְׁמֶ֙רֶת֙ מִשְׁכַּ֣ן יְהוָ֔ה כַּאֲשֶׁ֛ר צִוָּ֥ה יְהוָ֖ה אֶת־מֹשֶֽׁה׃
>
> even of the children of Israel’s half, Moses took one drawn out of every fifty, both of man and of beast, and gave them unto the Levites, that kept the charge of the tabernacle of the LORD; as the LORD commanded Moses.

This verse does not mention the donkeys, sheep and cattle. What happened to them? Why are they omitted here?

Comment: It says "beast"....

Answer (score 3):

It *says* "animals" in verse 47.

But if that's not enough for you, *ibn Ezra* clarifies that "animals" in [verse 30](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&pgnum=419) (which you translated "cattle") means animals not otherwise listed but "animals" in [verse 47](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14084&st=&pgnum=419) means animals generally [i.e. including those listed in verse 30].

Comment: Based on this definition, is the phrasing on verse 30 a case of *prat v'klal*?

Comment: @DanF http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask